# Please explain Hall effect in p type semiconductors without the use of holes

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, hall-effect

The movement of holes means the movement of electrons in opposite direction, so in Hall Effect the particles on which force is applied finally must be electrons, so there must be no positive charge appearing in this scenario.

Comment: The model that works uses holes.

Comment: @JohnDoty holes just mean the absence of electrons eventually it is the electrons which move so i am asking whether it can be explained by the movement of electrons not by the hole(which means absence of electron)

Comment: The "electrons" in condensed matter don't generally behave like electrons in a vacuum.

Comment: when magnetic field is applied why are these electrons moving in opposite direction to the force applied on them as the hole movement denotes

Comment: Semiconductors, doped or not, are electrically neutral. And holes are a very necessary part of understanding semiconductors and even some metals. E.g. under certain conditions in aluminum the hall effect will indicate a positive charge carrier. Think on that for a bit...

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/538629/how-can-we-explain-that-beryllium-has-positive-charge-carriers-as-a-metal-from may be of some use as well. In solid state physics you really need to use holes.

Comment: @SolomonSlow - without treating holes as an equal to electrons you have difficulty using detailed balance to discuss majority and minority carrier concentrations in a doped semiconductor in the first place. And certainly if you can't get there in a bulk region you aren't getting to a junction either.

Comment: @JonCuster, Oops! I deleted my "comment," thinking you had not read it. In case anyone else is wondering,  I asked Jon why it is necessary to talk about holes if there is no P/N junction in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Electrons at the top of the valence band have negative [effective mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass_(solid-state_physics)). Holes are just a way of inverting the band's energy diagram, speaking in terms of the positive charges of the lack of electrons instead of the negative charges of the electrons themselves.

If you want to understand the Hall effect in terms of electrons instead, take the negative effective mass of an electron, put it into the second Newton's law, and see where the acceleration will be directed with respect to the electric field.

Comment: the electrons are getting deflected in the same direction as holes. i am not getting the right hall voltage if the electrons are getting deflected in same direction as holes

Comment: @RaqibSyed Did you change all the relevant signs? Mass, charge, drift velocity.

Comment: the magnetic force getting applied on them is in the same direction as they are travelling in opposite directions and have opposite charges

Comment: @RaqibSyed It's right that the force is applied in the same direction. But now apply Newton's second law to this force to get acceleration. Don't forget that the mass is negative in this case.

Comment: Remember $F = ma$, so if the magnetic force is the same yet $m$ becomes $-m$, what happens to $a$?

Comment: where did the negative mass originate from

Comment: @RaqibSyed see the link to the article about effective mass that I gave in the body of my answer.

Comment: "the electrons respond to electric and magnetic forces by gaining velocity in the opposite direction compared to normal; even though these electrons have negative charge, they move in trajectories as if they had positive charge (and positive mass)" can this statement have a classical explanation

Comment: @RaqibSyed no, the band structure itself is a product of interference of the electron waves scattered by the crystal lattice. The effective mass is introduced in terms of this band structure. In particular, the transition of an electron from the bottom of a band to the top (changing its effective mass from positive to negative) can give rise to [Bloch oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_oscillation), which is a completely non-classical behavior.

Comment: ok actually i dont have the complete idea of quantum mechanics but this topic is being taught to us thank u for your help as i have a little bit of idea about it now